# How the Bounty Rules Applied

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) it is mentioned that `Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty` but I have saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075107/entity-framework-repository-check-big-text) with the bounty of `50` whose reputation point is `34`. I wonder how he could able to start a bounty?

Comment: He used to have a reputation of 84. 84 - 50 = 34

Comment: so the reputation is deducted when we start the bounty itself?

Comment: yup. ··········

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Placing a bounty *immediately* subtracts that score from your reputation (not when it is awarded) - essentially those points are in escrow, pending an accepted answer. So the user's reputation was *by necessity* sufficient at the time they placed the bounty.